# Project Built on Visual Studio 2015 is failing in windows 10

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc, windows-10

We are facing some issues regarding the launch of application in Windows 10.

The project is built using Visual Studio 2015 in Windows 10 is failing to run in another machine, where VC++ 2010 & 2015 redistributable is present.

However, we have got another copy of same source built on Visual studio 2010 in Windows 7, this is working fine in Windows 10 where VC++ 2010 & 2015 redistributable is present.

In the event viewer, it says MSVCP140.DLL, VCRUNTIME140D.DLL, MFC140d.dll etc.. like this DLL missing is the error.

Even though we have VC++ 2015 redistributable is present & i checked the same DLL in System 32 & Wow64 folder still the exe is not launching in Windows 10.

What could be the reason?

Comment: Well, its probably after a specific version - I did a search on my machine for msvcp140.dll and found many different sizes, indicating at least different versions

Comment: You are trying to run the debug version. It's quite normal that the debug version won't run on a computer where Visual Studio is not installed. Try with the release version, that should work.

Comment: I tried release mode, still its not launching, same error

Comment: I created a sample project, if i set MutliBye character set then application is not running in different workstation where VC++ 2015 redistributables installed. If i set Unicode in this case, application works as expected.

Comment: Getting these filenames in error messages is very strange with a release build: "VCRUNTIME140D.DLL", "MFC140d.dll": these two dlls are only used by debug builds. Note the letter __D__ right before the .dll extension.

Comment: @Jabberwocky, Great, thanks for the help, but in release mode also in event viewer i can see error like MSVCP140 & mfc140.dll was not found. So same issue i'm seeing without D for relesae mode

Comment: @Jabberwocky, I created a sample project, if i set MutliBye character set then application is not running in different workstation where VC++ 2015 redistributables installed. If i set Unicode in this case, application works as expected. What could be reason?

Comment: @Naruto I have no idea, but this is a different question.

Comment: Thanks, i will post it as separate question,